# Partitioned view without Check

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following view

```
create view V(CategoryId, ...) 
as
select 1, .... from T1 union all
select 2, .... from T2 union all
select 3, .... from T3 union all
select 4, .... from T4 union all
select 5, .... from T5 union all
...
```

I didn't add the column `CategoryId` to the underline tables because each table has the constant value, and thus I cannot add the `Check(CategoryId = 1)` since the column doesn't physically exist.

The following query will scan all the tables. Is it a way to let the execution plan scan only one of the table for the query?

```
declare @id tinyint = (....); 
select * from V where CategoryId = @id and ...
```

Comment: Are you *sure* it scans all the tables? Look at the actual execution plan and "number of executions" on the ones that shouldn't be scanned. Or the output of `SET STATISTICS IO ON;`. Also I presume you didn't intend to have multiple `T1` references in your example view definition?

Comment: I've updated the question. The sql `select ... from CategoryId = 1` will scan only one table. However, sql `declare @id tinyint = (...); select ... from CategoryId = @id` will scan all the tables.

Comment: Even with your edit I don't see it scan all tables. They appear in the plan but the table access has a filter with a startup predicate before it so only executed when the parameter value requires it. Have you checked either of the two things I mentioned in my first comment?

Comment: I add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` at the end of the view definition. It will recompile execution plan for specific value of your `@id` variable. Just to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The following query will scan all the tables. Is it a way to let the
>   execution plan scan only one of the table for the query?

First check that this is actually happening.

```
CREATE TABLE T1(X INT)
CREATE TABLE T2(X INT)
CREATE TABLE T3(X INT)

GO

CREATE VIEW V(CategoryId, X)
AS
  SELECT 1, X
  FROM   T1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, X
  FROM   T2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, X
  FROM   T3
```

Then running

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;

DECLARE @id TINYINT = 1;

SELECT *
FROM   V
WHERE  CategoryId = @id
```

Returns

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0
Table 'T1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 0, physical reads 0
```

Showing neither `T2` or `T3` were accessed. The plan looks like

[image]

The filter operators have a start up predicate and only execute the scan underneath if the value of `@id` matches that relevant to that part of the plan.

In the actual execution plan if you look at the properties of the `T2` and `T3` scan operators then "Number of Executions" shows up as `0`.

You could also evaluate

```
DECLARE @id TINYINT = 1;

SELECT *
FROM   V
WHERE  CategoryId = @id 
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems this is one of the example of inaccurate execution plan. I had revised question on this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308267/partitioned-view-execution-plan