# Partitioned view execution plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The following is the test tables and the partitioned view.

```
use tempdb
go
SET STATISTICS IO ON
create table T1 (C int primary key); 
create table T2 (C int primary key); 
create table T3 (C int primary key); 
create table T4 (C int primary key); 
create table T5 (C int primary key); 
create table T6 (C int primary key); 
create table TA (c int primary key, id int); 

insert into dbo.T1(C) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8)
insert into dbo.T2(C) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8)
insert into dbo.T3(C) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8)
insert into dbo.T4(C) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8)
insert into dbo.T5(C) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8)
insert into dbo.T6(C) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8)
insert into TA values (1, 1), (2, 2)
go
create view V(Id, C)
as
select 1, * from T1 union all
select 2, * from T2 union all
select 3, * from T3 union all
select 4, * from T4 union all
select 5, * from T5 union all
select 6, * from T6
```

However, the following view will scan all the tables? What's the best way to avoid it?

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.V join TA on TA.c = v.c
where ta.c = 2 and ta.id = v.id
option (recompile)
```

Answer (score 1):

This rewrite adds filters with startup predicates to the plan and avoids accessing the other tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM   TA
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT *
                    FROM   dbo.V
                    WHERE  TA.c = v.c
                           AND ta.id = v.id) CA
WHERE  TA.c = 2
```

`STATISTICS IO` results of this are

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0
Table 'T2'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0
Table 'TA'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0
```

Compared with the original results of

```
Table 'T6'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0
Table 'T5'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0
Table 'T4'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0
Table 'T3'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0
Table 'T2'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0
Table 'T1'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0
Table 'TA'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0
```

Comment: Thanks. Should the `outer apply` to `cross apply` so it's semantically equal to the original sql? However, `cross apply` will scan all the tables though.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 - Yes `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY` are semantically the same in this case but seems the `CROSS APPLY` just gets transformed into the same `INNER JOIN` plan as you started off with.

Comment: I found it will scan all the tables if add `CA.c is not null` when using `cross apply` too.